# Pipe a terminal?

Tags: regex, unix, terminal, pipe

Do you know of any way that I can pipe a terminal (not stdout) through something that will modify what I see on that terminal in realtime?

In particular, I would like to pipe my terminal display through an environment that will let me rewrite it as I please using regex find-and-replace...

My first application would be: auto-colorize any info on-screen that can be easily recognized with regex, as I asked here: [Colorize B&W terminal-based apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905470/colorize-bw-terminal-based-apps)

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing gets really deep into the internals of Unix terminal handling. However, you might be able to use the source for something like [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) as a starting point. `tmux` creates virtual terminal sessions that the user can switch between, tile windows, and so on. It contains the infrastructure you would need to do the sort of task you are imagining.

Answer (score 2):

For this, you need a program (something like GNU screen), which simulates a virtual terminal for the program to be run, and connects the real terminal with the virtual terminal by moving data between them. The place to implement your changes to the data stream is during this moving of the data.